# problem with resample in pandas with default example

Tags: pandas, importerror

using pandas and try to resample

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='T')
series = pd.Series(range(9), index=index)
series.resample('3T').mean()
```

getting:

ImportError: cannot import name 'ResamplerWindowApply' from 'pandas.core.apply' (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py)

any hint??

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I am using pandas 1.2.1; did try to upgrade pandas --> no change

Comment: @Bashton This is clearly an Anaconda installation. Recommending someone update with pip is likely to FUBAR their installation. Go to the Anaconda prompt and do `conda update --all`

Comment: The issue is not reproducible. The code works as expected in pandas 1.3.4